# Calculating a difference for an item, between most recent dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to calculate the difference between weights of my loaded trucks everyday. Basically, I want to know the incremental weight amounts carried each day. In theory, the trucks will be running on a daily basis, but I'm using a simplified data set on my mock database.

This is the code I've come up with:

```
--create table dbo.truck 
--(TruckID int, Weight float, datetrunc date, weightdiff float)
declare @dt1 datetime, @dt2 datetime
select @dt2 = max(datetrunc) from truck
select @dt1 = max(datetrunc) from truck where datetrunc < @dt2
select @dt1 [dt1], @dt2 [dt2]

SELECT t1.truckid, t2.weight - t1.weight [WeightDiff]
FROM truck t1
inner join truck t2 ON t1.truckid = t2.truckid
WHERE t1.datetrunc = @dt1
AND   t2.datetrunc = @dt2


UPDATE truck SET WeightDiff = x.WeightDiff
FROM (
SELECT t1.truckid, t2.weight - t1.weight [WeightDiff]
FROM truck t1
inner join truck t2 ON t1.truckid = t2.truckid
WHERE t1.datetrunc = @dt1
AND   t2.datetrunc = @dt2
) AS X
WHERE truck.datetrunc = @dt2
AND x.truckid = truck.truckid


SELECT t1.truckid,  @dt2,      t2.weight - t1.weight 
FROM truck t1
inner join truck t2 ON t1.truckid = t2.truckid
WHERE t1.datetrunc = @dt1
AND   t2.datetrunc = @dt2
```

I'm hoping for a difference between each date to show. However, it is only dsiplaying the difference between the latest dates, while deleting&null the other rows:

```
TruckID Weight  datetrunc   weightdiff
1   1000    2019-03-01  NULL
2   1111    2019-03-01  NULL
3   1222    2019-03-01  NULL
1   1050    2019-03-15  NULL
2   1700    2019-03-15  NULL
3   1400    2019-03-15  NULL
1   1125    2019-03-31  75
2   1725    2019-03-31  25
3   1600    2019-03-31  200
```

I want:

```
TruckID Weight  datetrunc   weightdiff
1   1000    2019-03-01  NULL
2   1111    2019-03-01  NULL
3   1222    2019-03-01  NULL
4   1400    2019-03-01  NULL
1   1050    2019-03-15  50
2   1700    2019-03-15  589
3   1400    2019-03-15  178
4   1490    2019-03-15  90
1   1125    2019-03-31  75
2   1725    2019-03-31  25
3   1600    2019-03-31  200
4   1900    2019-03-31  510
```

Notice how some TruckID 4 were completed deleted from my dataset. Also, how it replaces the weight difference.

I can't seem to figure how to make my data display properly. Any suggestions help, thanks!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2008

```
select a.truckid, a.weight, a.datetrunc, (a.weight - c.weight) weightdiff
from truck a
outer apply (select top 1 weight from truck b where b.datetrunc<a.datetrunc and b.truckid=a.truckid order by b.datetrunc desc) c
```

Newer SQL Server

```
select truckid, weight, datetrunc, weight - lag(weight) over (partition by truckid order by datetrunc) weightdiff
from truck
```